# Underline text in PDF on Mouse Text Selection in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, aspose.pdf

Can anyone guide me how can I achieve this in my web application ? I am using Aspose.PDF Third Party dll in order to achieve this.I want to select text in PDF using Mouse and then want to underline selected text.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have selected the string over PDF file, you may get the selected string and then parse the selected string to Aspose.Pdf for .NET API and then have tried updating its formatting with underlined text. Please take a look over following code snippet to underline searched string.

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document("c:/pdftest/Table_abc.pdf");

// Create TextAbsorber object to find all instances of the input search phrase
TextFragmentAbsorber textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber("Employee_Name");

// Accept the absorber for all the pages
pdfDocument.Pages.Accept(textFragmentAbsorber);

// Get the extracted text fragments
TextFragmentCollection textFragmentCollection = textFragmentAbsorber.TextFragments;

// Loop through the fragments
foreach (TextFragment textFragment in textFragmentCollection)
{
    // Underline the selected string
    textFragment.TextState.Underline = true;
}
// Save resulting PDF document.
pdfDocument.Save("c:/pdftest/TextUnderlined.pdf");
```

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.